# Postman (chrome app) returns 500 internal server error when passing post JSON code to API (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, postman

I am working on a backend API using Codeigniter framework to store data in database(mysql). I am trying to test the API using Postman but it returns the specified error. [postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfdRi.jpg)

```
public function addScanData()
{       
    //get user details
    $image_name = $this->input->post('image_name');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone');
    $time = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $mail = $this->input->post('mail');

    //To insert user data into database
    $user = array(
        'image_name' => $image_name,
        'name' => $name,
        'phone_number' => $phone_number,
        'time' => $time
    );

    $this->db->insert('user_details',$user);    
}
```

above is the sample code.

Comment: What is your error content?

Comment: 500 error is an Internal Server error, it will be triggered when you have any error in code ( mostly missing ; ), or in your case it may even be because you try to access a property of non-object... you could first check that does the $this->input->post even has any data, if you read the error content, it gives you alot information

Comment: It always return the null value

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the input helper or the db model?

Through the autoload.php in config or by having something like:

```
$this->load->helper('name');
```

or

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

And normally if you are deving you will get some info from the response containing the error.

Comment: in the body of the response you have an HTML(on the postman client). there you should be able to see what kind of error you got. can you post the response body of the postman client here, please. in your printscreen we're not able to see that part